# Evaluate $\int_0^1 \cos^{-1} x\ dx$ by first finding $\frac{d}{dx}(x\cos^{-1} x)$

Tags: integration, derivatives, trigonometric-integrals

## Question

Evaluate $$\int_0^1 \cos^{-1} x\ dx$$ by first finding the value of $$\frac{d}{dx}(x\cos^{-1} x).$$

## My Working

As the question said to evaluate $$\frac{d}{dx}(x\cos^{-1} x),$$ I used the product rule to differentiate. We first have to let $u=x$ and $v=\cos^{-1} x$, so

\begin{align}
& \quad\frac{d}{dx}(x\cos^{-1} x)\\
&=u^\prime v+v^\prime u\\
&=1\cdot \cos^{-1}x + x\cdot\frac{-1}{\sqrt{1-x^2}}\\
&=\cos^{-1}x-\frac{x}{\sqrt{1-x^2}}
\end{align}

Unfortunately, after that, I have no idea about how to proceed, but I think that we should go somewhere from

$$\int\left[\frac{d}{dx}(x\cos^{-1}x)\right]\ dx+\int\frac{x}{\sqrt{1-x^2}}\ dx=\int \cos^{-1}x???$$

Thank you for your help!

Comment: Yes. Now let $u = 1-x^2$ and use the fundamental theorem of calculus to conclude. The idea here is that integration by parts is derived by messing with the differentiation product rule formula, and this calculation is making that explicit.

Comment: For the first integral in LHS, use the fundamental theorem of calculus: $\int_0^1 \frac{d}{dx}f(x)\,dx=f(1)-f(0)$. For the second, hint: compute the derivative of $\sqrt{1-x^2}$.

Comment: @Feng Thank you! Also, should I rewrite all the integrals as with the lower bound of 0 and the higher bound of 1?

Comment: @CheeseCake You're welcome. Yes. Because you are going to compute the *definite* integral.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

After seeing the helpful comments, I can start using $u$-substitution for the solution. Let $u=1-x^2$, then

\begin{align}
\frac{du}{dx}&=-2x\\
du&=-2x\ dx\\
\int_0^1\frac{x}{\sqrt{1-x^2}}&=-\frac{1}{2}\int^1_0\frac{-2x}{\sqrt{1-x^2}}\ dx\\
&=-\frac{1}{2}\int^1_0 \frac{1}{\sqrt{u}}\ du\\
&=-\frac{1}{2}\int^1_0 u^{-\frac{1}{2}}\ du\\
&=-\frac{1}{2}\left[2u^\frac{1}{2}\right]^1_0\\
&=-\frac{1}{2}\left[2(1-x^2)^\frac{1}{2}\right]^1_0\\
&=-\frac{1}{2}\left(2\sqrt{1-1^2}-2\sqrt{1-0^2}\right)\\
&=-\frac{1}{2}\cdot-2\\
&=1\\
\int^1_0\left[\frac{d}{dx}(x\cos^{-1}x)\right]\ dx&=\left[x\cos^{-1}x\right]^1_0\\
&=0\\
\int^1_0\cos^{-1}x\ dx&= 0+1=1
\end{align}

Comment: Your last line shouldn't have an $x$ in it (just $\cos^{-1}$) but everything else looks great! Nice work, and nicely done writing everything up in TeX code! Feel free to accept your own answer to close the question. (I think it allows you to, and if not you could always make it community wiki and then accept it)

Comment: @BrevanEllefsen Thank you for spotting the mistake! Also, I can only accept my answer after at least two days of posting it, so I cannot right now.

Answer (score 0):

We may use the trigonometric substitution $y=\cos^{-1} x$ to transform the integral into
$$
\begin{aligned}
\int_0^1 \cos ^{-1} x d x &=\int_0^{\frac{\pi}{2}} y \sin y d y \\
&=-\int_0^{\frac{\pi}{2}} y d(\cos y) \\
&=-[y \cos y]_0^{\frac{\pi}{2}}+\int_0^{\frac{\pi}{2}} \cos y d y \quad \textrm{ (By IBP)}\\
&=[\sin y]_0^{\frac{\pi}{2}} \\
&=1
\end{aligned}
$$

Answer (score 0):

Integration by parts gives
$$
\begin{aligned}
\int_0^1 \cos ^{-1} x d x &=\left[x \cos ^{-1} x\right]_0^1+\int_0^1 \frac{x}{\sqrt{1-x^2}} d x \\
&=-\frac{1}{2} \int_0^1u^{-\frac{1}{2}} d u, \quad (\textrm{ where }u=1-x^2)\\
&=-\frac{1}{2} \cdot 2\left[u^{\frac{1}{2}}\right]_1^0 \\
&=1
\end{aligned}
$$